# CSS won't work on a specific class name

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, class, less

I have a class name that has double dashes inside it. The problem is that the CSS does not work on the class.

The class is `.menu--dropdown--item--link` and the LESS is this:

```
.menu {
  &--dropdown {
    &--item {
      &--link {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        line-height: 28px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        display: inline-flex;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And that compiles to this:

```
.menu--dropdown--item--link {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="menu--dropdown dropdown-menu icon-w-text" role="menu">
  <li class="menu--dropdown--item ">
    <a class="menu--dropdown--item--link" href="http://www.socialdeal.nl.sd-dev-006.socialdeal.work/mijn-vouchers/">
        <i class="icon-vouchers">
  </i> Mijn vouchers
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have looked if a CSS class has a maximum number of characters but there is no maximum. I have also created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5uqvnjzp/), but it works.

Am I not seeing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the class name is correct, have you checked the web inspector for your applied styles?

Comment: Double hyphens are not a problem. Your problem should be because of something else. Can you reproduce the problem in a Fiddle with a simplified version of your actual code?

Comment: @Andreas I have checked it in Chrome. And if I apply the CSS to the parent of the link it works. But it does not work on the link

Comment: @Harry Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eabz3m2x/)

Comment: @bristov But that one works. The padding etc are applied. That's why I asked if you can reproduce the problem in a fiddle.

Comment: @Harry I can't, that is the problem. The HTML is right, the CSS is right. I just don't get why it is not working. But when I change it to a ID it works. (In my site)

Comment: Right click the 'not-working' link -> inspect element and then look at the CSS applied to that element, that should show you which styles are being applied and where they come from.

Comment: @bristov: Then it is difficult for us to help because we atleast need to see the problem in action. The code given here has no problems whatsoever.

Comment: Can you send the url of your site, please?

Comment: @DavidThomas There is no CSS applied to it what so ever. That is the problem. Like Harry said the code that I have posted here is fine and it works on JSfiddle. It does not work in my site.

Comment: @IvanChaer I am working on a new menu for the site and the new menu is not live yet. So the only thing that you can see on the site is the old menu which works fine.

Comment: @bristov "when I change it to a ID it work" - when you change what?